# reiniciar tabla al cerrar modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este codgio

```
var d = "";
    $("#bntParametro").click(function () {
        var ajaxParam = null;
        ajaxParam = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendTophp/consultarParametros.php",
        }).done(function (param) {
            d = '<tr>' +
                '<th rowspan="3" >Acción</th>' +
                '<th rowspan="3" >Categoria compoenete</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Aliados</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Cadenas</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Constructor local</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Constructor nacional</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Exterior</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Mayorista</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Salas de venta</th>' +
                '<th colspan="2">Saeta</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '<th>Aum cant</th>' +
                '<th>Aum pre</th>' +
                '</tr>';
            for (var i in param) {
                d += '<tr>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnEditar" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-danger btnEditar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>' +
                    '<th>' + param[i][0] + '</th>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][1] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][2] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][3] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][4] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][5] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][6] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][7] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][8] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][9] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][10] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][11] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][12] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][13] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][14] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][15] + '</td>' +
                    '<td contenteditable="false">' + param[i][16] + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            }
            $("#tblGrid").append(d);

            $(".btnEditar").click(function () {
                var parametrosNuevos = [];
                var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
                var currentTD2 = $(this).parents('tr').find('th');
                for (var j in currentTD2) {
                    var compo = currentTD2[j].innerText
                    parametrosNuevos.push(compo);
                    break;
                }
                for (var i in currentTD) {
                    if (i > "0") {
                        var conteo = parseInt(currentTD[i].innerText);
                        parametrosNuevos.push(conteo);
                        if (i == "16") {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                debugger
                if ($(this).html() === '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>') {
                    currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
                    $.each(currentTD, function () {
                        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
                    });
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: "sendTophp/insertarParametros.php",
                        data: { parametrosNuevos }
                    }).done(function (respuesta) {
                        debugger
                    }).fail(function (response) {

                    });
                    $.each(currentTD, function () {
                        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
                    });
                }
                $(this).html($(this).html() == '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>' ? '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>')
            });
        }).fail(function (responseErr) {
            console.log("error" + responseErr);
        });
```

y este es el modal

×
                Parametros
            
            
                
                
            
            
                 Close
                 Guardar

```
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

El problema que tengo es que cierro y abro el modal y vuelve y me carga la table n veces a  y no se como hacer para que cuando se le de cerrar se reinicie el modal y me vuelva a cargar los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error lo tienes porque nunca limpias el body de la modal, es decir la primera vez crear el contenido de la tabla cierras la modal y no limpias entonces queda ese contenido mas el nuevo cuando vuelvas abrir la modal, para eso **bootstrap** ha creo un manejador de eventos, en tu caso puedes usar el evento `hidden.bs.modal` el cual se dispara cuando tu modal se ha cerrado:

```
$('#tuModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#tuModal .modal-body').find("#tblGrid").html("");
});
```

donde **#tuModal** seria el **id** o la **clase** de tu modal.

Answer (score 2):

te hace falta agregar en la función que abre tu modal, la siguiente linea

```
$("#tblGrid").html('');
```

esto lo que hace es quitar el contenido previo del contenedor, lo puedes poner al principio de tu función que abre el modal o en la función que tengas para cerrar el modal.

espero te sirva, Saludos.